# How to populate a vector using x-macros?

Tags: c++

I have a list of enums that I want to convert to a string and populate a vector using X-Macros:

### Foo.h file

```
#define LIST(T)        \                            
    T(A, "a")          \                                    
    T(B, "b")          \                                
    T(C, "c")       



class Foo {

// Enum of all Symbols above.
#define T(symbol, name) symbol,
    enum Symbol {LIST(T) NUM_OF_SYMBOLS};
#undef T

// Will Hold enums in string form (ie. "A", "B", "C")
// All instances of Foo should share one vector.
static std::vector<std::string> typeName;

} // Foo
```

### Note

I do not want any reallocations to occur with vector so I use reserve below. I also do not want vector to call the default constructor of string for no reason just to move strings "A", "B", "C" to those values (Trust me. My real LIST is much bigger). typeName is static because I don't want every instance to redefine it. Each instance should go to one source to get it's type in string form, which will later be accessed like this `fooInstance.typeName[fooInstance.someSymbol]`

### Problem

The code below causes an error, ***no type named typeName in Foo***, which I believe is because it lies in the global scope. What is the correct practice to make this work. The correct answer does not need to happen at compile-time.

### Foo.cpp file

```
// Define static vector.
std::vector<std::string> Foo::typeName;

// Reserve space so no reallocations occur
Foo::typeName.reserve(Foo::NUM_OF_SYMBOLS);

// For all symbols (ie. A, B, C), insert into vector as
// "A", "B", "C"
#define T(symbol, name) Foo::typeName.emplace_back(#symbol);

    LIST(T)

#undef T
```

Comment: Are you really trying to call `reserve` and `emplace_back` at global scope? Or is the code above just an abbreviation of your real code? You should clarify.

Comment: If the size is fixed, why use a vector? Why not an array?

Comment: @john I clarified that under the heading, Problem.

Comment: @melpomene I’m not too familiar with arrays in C++. Would it call the default C’tor of each string?

Comment: That depends on how you initialize it.

Comment: @melpomene If you don’t mind, show me using x macro

Comment: @Amjad So you need to move the calls to `reserve` and `emplace_back` so they aren't at global scope. In C++ you can't have statements at global scope, only inside functions.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```cpp
#define T(symbol, name) name,
inline static std::vector<std::string> typeName{ LIST(T) };
#undef T
```

Comment: Would this call default C’tor of each string and then move?

Comment: @Amjad If I remember correctly, it might even copy the strings rather than moving them. If that worries you, you could use a `std::vector<const char *>`.

Comment: @Amjad The default ctor of strings is "free", so why worry? But no, it doesn't call the default ctor. It can't move the elements because the initializers are not `std::string`, they're `const char *`, so a copy must be made.

Comment: @melpomene please explain how it’s “free”

Comment: @Amjad It does a constant amount of work and that amount is small. It only has to set two or three member variables.